# Seekbar with 1 decimal

Tags: java, android, save, decimal, seekbar

I need my seekbar to show 1 decimal, ex 4.5.
It show as a integer now.

```
seekBar.setProgress((int)Float.parseFloat(Item.getRating()));
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this help you

```
aSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        float value = ((float)progress / 10.0);
        // value now holds the decimal value between 0.0 and 10.0 of the progress
        // Example:
        // If the progress changed to 45, value would now hold 4.5
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});
```